How do I determine if a path is a fifo?
I have some bash shell code that runs
if [[ ! -s "$1" ]]

to determine if $1 is a non-empty file
This test fails if $1 is a fifo, even though the fifo has data in it ready to be read.
Is there a bash shell test I can run to determine if a path is a fifo?

Have you read the bash man page? Or the output of help test?
